# A general surface integral over the unit sphere in polar coordinates

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

Given is the unit sphere and a function $f(\alpha, \beta)$ on the sphere.  $\alpha$ is the angle from the north pole (i.e. $\alpha=\pi/2 -$ latitude) and $\beta$ is the longitude. How do I calculate the surface integral of $f$ over the whole surface of the sphere?

I know that this is **wrong:**

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^\pi f(\alpha, \beta) \ \ \ d\alpha \ d\beta $$

Is this integral:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^\pi f(\alpha, \beta) \ \ \ \sin \alpha \ \ \ d\alpha \ d\beta $$

the correct one? At least for $f=1$ the result seems correct.

Comment: Yes, this last expression is correct. Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) link, the additional factor going from the first equation to the second equation com from the Jacobian

Comment: Would you change your comment to an answer?

Comment: Absolutely, will add a bit more of detail in just a few

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can figure out the right size of the differential area element with the sketch below

[image]

The result is

$$
{\rm d}A = ({\rm d}\alpha)(\sin\alpha \ {\rm d}\beta) = \sin\alpha \  {\rm d}\alpha {\rm d}\beta
$$

So that the integral on a unit sphere of the function $f$ is

$$
\int_0^\pi{\rm d\alpha}\int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\beta ~\sin\alpha \  f(\alpha, \beta)
$$

Formally, you can get to the same result through the determinant of the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) matrix